# How can I solve for k for this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> A linear transformation T: $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ whose matrix is
>   $\begin{bmatrix}-3&-9&-9\\-3&-9& -10+k\end{bmatrix}$ is onto if $k \ne ? $

I put this matrix in RREF to get

\begin{bmatrix}1&3&3\\0&0&(-4+k/3)\end{bmatrix}

I know that onto means: Onto: says that its onto if each b in $\mathbb R^m$ is the image of at least one x in $\mathbb R^n$ What do they mean by "image"?

Answer (score 1):

We say that $b$ is the image of $a$ if $b = T a$.

Comment: So k then would have to be 12 yes?

Comment: Well, $-4 + k/3$ would have to be zero.

Comment: Sorry typo ^ lol

Comment: That can't be right, something is wrong. I've RREF wrong maybe?

Comment: Subtracting the top row from the bottom row I get $0 \; 0 \; k-1$ for the bottom row.  So presumably the condition should be $k \neq 1$.

Comment: god im SO STUPID

Answer (score 0):

The rank of the matrix have to be maximal in this case, so $-9\neq -10+k \Longrightarrow k\neq 1$